# MySQL - Select only the last modified (or NULL value)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database table with the following structure:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | item_id |  name   |      modified       |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |    1829 | Item 1  | 2013-10-20 20:42:34 |
|  2 |    1737 | Item 2  | 2013-10-25 12:33:01 |
|  3 |    1829 | Item 3  | 2013-10-22 18:47:22 |
|  4 |    1737 | Item 2b | 2013-10-29 21:12:29 |
|  6 |    1829 | Item 3b | NULL                |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

What I'd like to do is, in a sole query, get all items, but if repeated only get those newer (modified field is newer) or whose modified field IS NULL.

So, what I'd get of this table would be:

```
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | item_id |  name   |      modified       |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 |    1829 | Item 1  | 2013-10-20 20:42:34 |
|  4 |    1737 | Item 2b | 2013-10-29 21:12:29 |
|  6 |    1829 | Item 3b | NULL                |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
```

I could do that with a second select, something like:

```
SELECT db_items.item_id, db_items.name, db_items.modified  
FROM (SELECT item_id, name, modified 
    FROM db_items 
    ORDER BY modified DESC) db_items 
GROUP BY item_id
```

But I'd like to know if it's possible without inner SELECTS (as this is only an example and I'd use it in more complicated queries).

Thanks for your time and answers!

Comment: Can't you just add another boolean-field that says "up to date", is true by default and which gets set to false once a new item with the same ID is inserted?

Comment: Though this could be a perfectly correct answer, it could be inconsistent through time, resulting in a "up_to_date = true" when it's not the last modified. The last modified must be the field taken into account. Thanks for the answer and your time anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Just try

```
SELECT *
FROM db_items 
GROUP BY item_id
ORDER BY modified DESC
```

Comment: If I try this, what I get is a GROUP BY item_id and from this group, ORDER them by the modified date. But the row chosen from the GROUP BY may be not the one I want to choose (for example, if it selects the last 'id' from each group, it would not be the last 'modified' - though sometimes they could be the same). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: If the type of that column is say `TIMESTAMP` then they will be ordered by time.

Comment: Or you could select the `MAX(modified)` from the group.